# Palindrome Checker for numbers

Tags: python, palindrome

I'm currently trying to do an assignment. I need to some help with my palindrome checker. This is what I've done so far

```
begin = int(input('Enter begin: '))
end = int(input('Enter end: '))

palindromes = 0
#Add your code here. You will want to start with a "for x in range" style loop.
for x in range(begin, end, -1):


print('There are', palindromes, 'palindrome(s) between', begin, 'and', end)
```

This is not a function. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Give a sample input and an expected output.

Comment: Make it output the number of palindromes and make it print the numbers which are palindromes inbetween the numbers begin and end

Comment: @Vaulstein my guess is he want to know number of palindrome between two points

Comment: SO is not here to do your homework, what is the *exact* problem you are having? your for loop needs a body. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check if a number is a palindrom would probably to treat it as a string, flip it, and check if the flipped string is equal to the original. From there on, it's just a loop that counts how many of these you've encounteres:

```
begin = int(input('Enter begin: '))
end = int(input('Enter end: '))

palindromes = 0
#Add your code here. You will want to start with a "for x in range" style loop.
for x in range(begin, end):
    if str(x) == str(x)[::-1]:
        palindromes += 1

print('There are', palindromes, 'palindrome(s) between', begin, 'and', end)
```

Comment: Also, how do I make it detect if the `begin` and `end` are already a palindrome?

Comment: @GabrielFraser the loop will iterate on them anyway, so they're treated just like any other element in the range. No special handling is needed.

Comment: The problem is when you use 111 as begin and 222 as end, it outputs 111 aswell. How do I stop that?

Comment: how do I make it skip the first line? so like it doesn't print the 111 aswell.

Comment: @Gabriel Fraser: Do you know what the `+` operator can do when you use it with numbers? Just use `for x in range(begin + 1, end):`.

Comment: Nope that doesn't fix it, It's supposed to start at zero. so if I choose 0 for beginning,